# Getting cellphone ID via WAP

Tags: php, wap, wml

I have a Motorola i475w and I want to do a WAP website that gets my cellphone's ID when I access it. The website uses PHP and WML. How can I get cellphone's ID using WML/PHP?

Comment: Talk to the NSA, they are the only ones who can do this.

Comment: I'm developing an application for a logistics enterprise. The application is intended to get mobile's ID and track vehicles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can only look at the headers. Sometimes the IMEI number is sent along with the headers but they are not guaranteed to be present.

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: The function getallheaders() will only work on devices that have Apache installed on them. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: The `getallheaders()` function is so you can see what headers are sent to your PHP server. Not for use on the device itself.